# Wordpress - Como pegar o valor de Custom Fields no tema

Tags: php, wordpress

Fala pessoal!

Sou iniciante no Wordpress e me deparei com um problema.

Estou tentando pegar o valor de um Custom Field que tem no wp-admin chamado Link do Cliente, lá no plugin do site na declaração de metaboxes, está declarado da seguinte maneira:

```
$metaboxes[] = array(

            'id'            => 'detalhesMetaboxCliente',
            'title'         => 'Detalhe do cliente',
            'pages'         => array( 'cliente' ),
            'context'       => 'normal',
            'priority'      => 'high',
            'autosave'      => false,
            'fields'        => array(

                array(
                    'name'  => 'Link do cliente: ',
                    'id'    => "{$prefix}cliente_link",
                    'desc'  => '',
                    'type'  => 'text'
                ),

            ),

        );
```

E o no tema, para buscar o Cliente cadastrado, está assim:

```
$clientePost = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'cliente', 'orderby' => 'id', 'order' => 'asc', 'posts_per_page' => 0 ) );

while ( $clientePost->have_posts() ) : $clientePost->the_post();
   // pega a foto do cliente
   $foto = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );
   $foto = $foto[0];
   // pega o link
   $link = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Maiacliente_link', true);
   echo $link;
endwhile; wp_reset_query();
```

O problema é que não estou conseguindo pegar o link, o valor está vindo vazio. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Veja se tem algum meta value associado ao seu post. Chame a função get_post_meta com um var_dump: `var_dump(get_post_meta($post->ID))`

Comment: Descobri, era Maia_cliente_link e não Maiacliente_link